# Specify function return type as template parameter in c++

Tags: c++, function, templates

I'm trying to give my function a return type of its template parameter(to improve type checking), which is a function reference.
Here is what I have attempted so far:

```
#include <Windows.h>

template <typename func>
decltype(auto) proxyFunction(LPCSTR dllPath, LPCSTR functionName){
    auto funcType = decltype(func);

    funcType funcPtr = (funcType) GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryA(dllPath), functionName);

    if(funcPtr)
        std::cout << "Proxy success" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Proxy fail" << std::endl;
    
    return funcPtr;
}

BOOL GetFileVersionInfoProxy(LPCSTR lptstrFilename, DWORD dwHandle, DWORD dwLen, LPVOID lpData){
    auto getFileVersion = proxyFunction<GetFileVersionInfoProxy>("C:\\Windows\\System32\\Version.dll", "GetFileVersionInfoA");
    getFileVersion(lptstrFilename, dwHandle, dwLen, lpData);
}
```

However, I am getting the following compile-time error with regards to `proxyFunction`:

> no instance of function template matches the argument list argument types are: (const char [32], const char [20])

I am not quite sure what to make of this error since it is rather vague. So I was wondering if anyone can explain what's the issue in my snippet?

P.S. I am using MS VS 2019 with C++ 17 standard, in case it is helpful.

Comment: `typename func` and `decltype(func)` don't work well togheter. What should be `func`? A type or a value?

Comment: @max66 `func` is expected to be a type of a function, as shown in the `GetFileVersionInfoProxy`.

Comment: But `GetFileVersionInfoProxy` itself is not a type, but a function. The template parameter should probably be `auto func` instead.

Comment: So, instead of `funcType`, you should use directly `func`: `func funcPtr = (func) GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryA(dllPath), functionName);`

Comment: Please put the _full_ error message from the "Output" window (NOT the "Error" window).

Comment: @arslancharyev31: Unrelated to everything, consider making `auto getFileVersion` a `static` local variable, so that `GetProcAddress` is only called once, rather than every time

Comment: You could also get rid of the C-style cast and use `reinterpret_cast`:  `reinterpret_cast<funcType>(GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryA(dllPath), functionName));`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `func` template parameter is already the type you want to return, so just use it as-is, there is no need to use `decltype(auto)`.  And your use of `auto funcType = decltype(func);` is just plain wrong.

Try this instead:

```cpp
template <typename funcType>
funcType proxyFunction(LPCSTR dllPath, LPCSTR functionName)
{
    funcType funcPtr = (funcType) GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryA(dllPath), functionName);

    if (funcPtr)
        std::cout << "Proxy success" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Proxy fail" << std::endl;
    
    return funcPtr;
}

BOOL GetFileVersionInfoProxy(LPCSTR lptstrFilename, DWORD dwHandle, DWORD dwLen, LPVOID lpData)
{
    using GetFileVersionInfoA_FuncType = BOOL (WINAPI *)(LPCSTR, DWORD, DWORD, LPVOID);

    auto getFileVersion = proxyFunction<GetFileVersionInfoA_FuncType>("C:\\Windows\\System32\\Version.dll", "GetFileVersionInfoA");
    if (getFileVersion)
        return getFileVersion(lptstrFilename, dwHandle, dwLen, lpData);

    return FALSE;
}
```

Alternatively, you can omit passing in the template parameter if you let the compiler deduce it for you:

```cpp
template <typename funcType>
bool proxyFunction(LPCSTR dllPath, LPCSTR functionName, funcType &funcPtr)
{
    funcPtr = (funcType) GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryA(dllPath), functionName);

    if (funcPtr)
        std::cout << "Proxy success" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Proxy fail" << std::endl;
    
    return (funcPtr != nullptr);
}

BOOL GetFileVersionInfoProxy(LPCSTR lptstrFilename, DWORD dwHandle, DWORD dwLen, LPVOID lpData)
{
    using GetFileVersionInfoA_FuncType = BOOL (WINAPI *)(LPCSTR, DWORD, DWORD, LPVOID);

    GetFileVersionInfoA_FuncType getFileVersion;
    if (proxyFunction("C:\\Windows\\System32\\Version.dll", "GetFileVersionInfoA", getFileVersion))
        return getFileVersion(lptstrFilename, dwHandle, dwLen, lpData);

    return FALSE;
}
```

**UPDATE:** based on @MooingDuck's comment, it looks like you are actually trying to pass your proxy function to the template and have it deduce the necessary parameters and return type for use with the DLL function.  If so, then try something more like this instead:

```cpp
template <typename RetType, typename... ArgTypes>
struct proxyTraits
{
    using funcType = RetType (WINAPI *)(ArgTypes...);
};

template <typename RetType, typename... ArgTypes>
auto proxyFunction(
    LPCSTR dllPath,
    LPCSTR functionName,
    RetType (*proxy)(ArgTypes...))
{
    using funcType = typename proxyTraits<RetType, ArgTypes...>::funcType;
    funcType funcPtr = (funcType) GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryA(dllPath), functionName);

    if (funcPtr)
        std::cout << "Proxy success" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Proxy fail" << std::endl;
    
    return funcPtr;
}

BOOL GetFileVersionInfoProxy(LPCSTR lptstrFilename, DWORD dwHandle, DWORD dwLen, LPVOID lpData)
{
    auto getFileVersion = proxyFunction("C:\\Windows\\System32\\Version.dll", "GetFileVersionInfoA", &GetFileVersionInfoProxy);
    if (getFileVersion)
        return getFileVersion(lptstrFilename, dwHandle, dwLen, lpData);

    return FALSE;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/X5quqm)

Comment: I think the OP is trying to pass `GetFileVersionInfoProxy` itself to `proxyFunction` in order to deduce the function signature, which could be achieved via `proxyFunction<decltype(GetFileVersionInfoProxy)>(...)` and then you don't need the `using` internally.

Comment: Separately, I think his problem is that `LPCSTR` is passing a wide string, and `"C:\\Windows\\System32\\Version.dll"` is a narrow string.

Comment: @MooingDuck Not true. There is nothing in this code that uses wide strings. Everything is using narrow strings.  `LPCSTR` is `const char*` only, and there is no use of `TCHAR` or the `L` prefix in this code. Maybe you are thinking of `LPCTSTR` instead (`const TCHAR*`).

Comment: @MooingDuck good point about passing in the proxy itself to the template to deduce the function pointer type. However, that won't work as-is since `GetFileVersionInfoProxy()` is not using the `__stdcall` calling convention, like `GetFileVersionInfoA()` does. Although template parameters can be used to work around that issue. I have updated my answer to show this.

Comment: Thanks. The updated answer seems to achieve what I desired, although in a bit different way. However, I struggle to comprehend what is going on here. What is the purpose of `proxyTraits`? What's the deal with all those `using` statements? And how come the `proxyFunction` can be called without specifying the template parameter? I would greatly appreciate if @RemyLebeau or anyone else could expand on the answer for educational purposes.

Comment: @arslancharyev31 the DLL function uses a different calling convention than the proxy function, so I use `proxyTraits` to help define that DLL function type for multiple uses. `using` statements are just the new and preferred way to create type aliases in C++11 and later, similar to `typedef`, just more flexible especially when dealing with templates. As for calling `proxyFunction` without specifying any template parameter values, the compiler can deduce the necessary template parameters based on how the caller uses function parameters that are connected to the template parameters.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) implements the kind of behavior I was looking for.

For example, if my dummy DLL function is defined as follows:

```
#include <Windows.h>

#define DllExport extern "C"  __declspec( dllexport )

DllExport int SQUARE(int number){
    return number * number;
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved){
    return TRUE;
}
```

Then I would import it as follows:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

HMODULE dummyHandle = nullptr;

template<typename signature>
std::function<signature> proxyFunction(HMODULE hModule, LPCSTR functionName){
    auto funcPtr = GetProcAddress(hModule, functionName);
    std::cout << (funcPtr ? "Proxy success" : "Proxy fail") << std::endl;
    return std::function<signature>(reinterpret_cast<signature*>(funcPtr));
}

int SQUARE(int number){
    auto proxy = proxyFunction<decltype(SQUARE)>(dummyHandle, __FUNCTION__);
    return proxy ? proxy(number) : -1;
}

int main(){
    dummyHandle = LoadLibraryA("C:\\Absolute\\Path\\To\\Dummy.dll");
    if(dummyHandle)
        std::cout << "Square of 7 is " << SQUARE(7) << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Failed to load dummy dll. Last Error: " << GetLastError() <<std::endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

I like this method since it enables basic static type checking without requiring definitions of auxiliary constructs. However, I still think that there is room for improvement. Every time we call `proxyFunction` we have to wrap the function into `decltype(...)`. Does anyone have any idea how to hide that bit within the `proxyFunction` in a simple manner?

Comment: Using `decltype` for the `signature` template parameter won't work in cases where the proxy function and target function use different calling conventions, as was the case in your original question (`GetFileVersionInfoA` uses `__stdcall`, but `GetFileVersionInfoProxy` uses `__cdecl`). I ran into that same issue when writing my answer, which is why I used a helper  `proxyTraits` struct to get around that issue.